# recieving error "android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"

Tags: android

I'm trying to use RecyclerView in my existing project, builds without errors but getting no class found error for the RecyclerView while inflating. Cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for helping!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class search_item1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<search_item1.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mData = null ;

    // 아이템 뷰를 저장하는 뷰홀더 클래스.
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1 ;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView) ;

            // 뷰 객체에 대한 참조. (hold strong reference)
            textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2) ;
        }
    }

    // 생성자에서 데이터 리스트 객체를 전달받음.
    search_item1(ArrayList<String> list) {
        mData = list ;
    }

    // onCreateViewHolder() - 아이템 뷰를 위한 뷰홀더 객체 생성하여 리턴.



    @Override
    public search_item1.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext() ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) ;

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search2_item, parent, false) ;
        search_item1.ViewHolder vh = new search_item1.ViewHolder(view) ;

        return vh ;
    }

    // onBindViewHolder() - position에 해당하는 데이터를 뷰홀더의 아이템뷰에 표시.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(search_item1.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String text = mData.get(position) ;
        holder.textView1.setText(text) ;
    }

    // getItemCount() - 전체 데이터 갯수 리턴.
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size() ;
    }
}
```

please help of this code Episode
Until the day I die, I look up to the sky.
I hope you're not ashamed
Even in the wind on the leaves,
I was distressed.
with a heart of singing the stars
Love all the dying.
And the way I've been given,
I have to walk.

The stars rub against the wind again tonight.

i have error of that:

```
2019-11-15 00:38:21.857 7571-7571/sungjusin.gatag3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sungjusin.gatag3, PID: 7571
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/sungjusin.gatag3-3-2f5OVMsm7-VXSs_MYnRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/sungjusin.gatag3-3-2f5OVMsm7-VXSs_MYnRg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at sungjusin.gatag3.search_item1.onCreateViewHolder(search_item1.java:67)
        at sungjusin.gatag3.search_item1.onCreateViewHolder(search_item1.java:13
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` in your xml file with `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

you are using to `androidx` so you can't use android.support.v7 ,
 so try to use :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>
```

instead of

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>
```